# Quickly calculating running totals in sql server using set based operations

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have some data that looks like this:

```
+---+--------+-------------+---------------+--------------+
|   |   A    |      B      |       C       |      D       |
+---+--------+-------------+---------------+--------------+
| 1 | row_id | disposal_id | excess_weight | total_weight |
| 2 | 1      | 1           | 0             | 30           |
| 3 | 2      | 1           | 10            | 30           |
| 4 | 3      | 1           | 0             | 30           |
| 5 | 4      | 2           | 5             | 50           |
| 6 | 5      | 2           | 0             | 50           |
| 7 | 6      | 2           | 15            | 50           |
| 8 | 7      | 2           | 5             | 50           |
| 9 | 8      | 2           | 5             | 50           |
+---+--------+-------------+---------------+--------------+
```

And I am transforming it to look like this:

```
+---+--------+-------------+---------------+--------------+
|   |   A    |      B      |       C       |      D       |
+---+--------+-------------+---------------+--------------+
| 1 | row_id | disposal_id | excess_weight | total_weight |
| 2 | 1      | 1           | 0             | 30           |
| 3 | 2      | 1           | 10            | 30           |
| 4 | 3      | 1           | 0             | 20           |
| 5 | 4      | 2           | 5             | 50           |
| 6 | 5      | 2           | 0             | 45           |
| 7 | 6      | 2           | 15            | 45           |
| 8 | 7      | 2           | 5             | 30           |
| 9 | 8      | 2           | 5             | 25           |
+---+--------+-------------+---------------+--------------+
```

Basically, I need to update the total_weight column by subtracting the sum of the excess_weights from previous rows in the table which belong to the same disposal_id.

I'm currently using a cursor because it's faster then other solutions I've tried (cte, triangular join, cross apply).  My cursor solution keeps a running total that is reset to zero for each new disposal_id, increments it by the excess weight, and performs updates when needed and runs in about 40 seconds.  The other solutions I've tried took anywhere from 3-5 minutes and I'm wondering if there is a relatively performant way to do this using set based operations?

Comment: I blogged about this recently: http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/running-totals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've spent a lot of time optimizing such queries, ended up with two performant options: either store precalculated running totals, as described in [Denormalizing to enforce business rules: Running Totals](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alexander_kuznetsov/archive/2009/01/23/denormalizing-to-enforce-business-rules-running-totals.aspx), or calculate them on the client, which is also fast and easy.

Answer (score 1):

The other solution you probably already tried is to do something like the answers found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860966/calculate-a-running-total-in-sqlserver)

Unless you are using Oracle, which has decent aggregates for cumulative sum, you're better off using a cursor.  At best, you're going to have to rejoin the table to itself or use another methods for what should be a O(n) operation. In general, the set based solution for problems like these are messy or really messy.

Answer (score 0):

'previous rows' implies an ordering.  so no - no set based operations there.

Oracle's LEAD and LAG are built for this, but SQL Server forces you into triangular joins... which i suppose you have investigated.